# removing impossible values in data in Python

Tags: python, database

I have data with incorrest value. Dealing with my problem in Python/Jupyter/Pandas.

The problem may appear for some of them : the percentage of success is greater than 1.

Here is what I did :[image]

I was expecting that it will solve my problem but apparently not. The maximum is still the same. How can I remove the impossible values please?

Comment: is the result in % or decimal form?...if it is indeed an error, what do you want to do with the values? delete them? replace them?

Comment: Where is the dataset from? The reason why it is like that is because you are probably not reassigning it back to the dataframe. it should be something like df = df[df['probability' <= 1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of the dataframe with the impossible values removed like this:

```
data_climbing_new = data_climbing.loc[data_climbing['Success Percentage'] <=1].copy()
```

This way you are filtering by localizing every row where 'Success Percentage' is less or equal than one. 
Using `.copy()` can be useful to not modify the original dataframe. Otherwise, you can even do the following:

```
data_climbing = data_climbing.loc[data_climbing['Success Percentage'] <=1]
```

Comment: so do we agree that I'm copying the data in my code at the beginning, then I have like an object X with all my data in it, and you are recommanding me to create Y from X such that I have X and Y. But never, I m touching the data in my excel file ?

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
data_climbing[data_climbing['Success Percentage'] <= 1]
```

is only show the data_climbing value with success percentage <= 1.

What you need is a variable assignment, or copy as @Cowflu described.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a bug somewhere because you should not have a percentage value greater than 1. If `date_climbing['Attempted'].loc[idx] == data_climbing['Succeeded'].loc[idx]` then the percentage should be 1 which will be your max.

To answer your question if that is what you want to do you can simply apply max to the slice.

```
max_ = data_climbing[data_climbing['Success Percentage'] <= 1].max()
```